# Node HTML in body

Tags: javascript, html, http, node.js

I wrote a simple HTTP sever that serves some HTML.
Here's the code :

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

  var html = '<DOCTYPE!>' +
    '  <html>' +
    '    <head>' +

    '      <title>' +
    '        Test page' +
    '      </title>' +

    '    </head>' +
    '  <body>' +

    '    <p>' +

    '      This is a test page !' +

    '    </p>' +

    '  </body>' +
    '  </html>';

  res.write(html);

  res.end();

}).listen(8080);
```

The resulting HTML page is the following :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<doctype!>
<title> Test page </title>
<p> This is a test page ! </p>
</doctype!>
</body>
</html>
```

So my questions are the following :

- Why is the html "string" included in the body of the HTML ?
- Is it possible to have indentation in the HTML besides using a template engine (jade) ?

And the last question is a bit separate :

- If I have a page called `index.html` which only shows `img.jpg`. How can I know that a users request to `img.jpg` is related to `index.html` ?
  What I mean by "related" is : "that `img.jpg` is a linked / a dependency of `index.html`".

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You should ask your "last question" as a separate question post. It's a completely different topic.

Comment: could you elaborate on the `the html "string" included in the body` part?

Comment: and indentation other than by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the html "string" included in the body of the HTML ?

That's because `<DOCTYPE!>` isn't valid. It should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As is, it appears more like an element to the browser, which attempts to normalize the markup and places it into the `<body>`.

---

> Is it possible to have indentation in the HTML besides using a template engine (jade) ?

Many template engines, including Jade, actually [minify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) the markup, removing all unnecessary whitespace for smaller bandwidth consumption.

But, you could look at using a "beautifier," such as [html](https://npmjs.org/package/html).

---

> If I have a page called index.html which only shows img.jpg. How can I know that a users request to img.jpg is related to index.html ? What I mean by "related" is : "that img.jpg is a linked / a dependency of index.html".

You can view "Resources" in most in-browser debuggers, which will list images, scripts, stylesheets, etc. that your page has requested.

You could also try [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) your application, perhaps with [jsdom](https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom):

```
jsdom.env('http://localhost:8080/', [
    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'
],
function (err, window) {
    var $ = window.$;

    var hrefs = $('a[href]').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('href');
    }).get();
    console.log(hrefs);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your long answer ! :D

Answer (score 1):

That's not actually the resulting HTML. The HTML your server serves is exactly what you think it's serving... The browser sees something wrong with that HTML.

`<DOCTYPE!>`

The browser doesn't know what `<DOCTYPE!>` is, so it assumes it's some sort of arbitrary tag. When a browser sees an arbitrary tag, it assumes it was meant to be in the body. And with unbalanced-tag error correction, it closes your `<DOCTYPE!>` tag with `</DOCTYPE!>` at the end of the body.

What you meant to use was `<!DOCTYPE>` or more likely, `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Actually, `<!DOCTYPE>` is also technically invalid HTML (according to the W3C validator). You need to specify a type if you're going to be using the `<!DOCTYPE>` "tag".

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you for your quick answer ! Any idea for the two other ones ?